# Understanding Android Launch modes with splash screens

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher, back-stack, launchmode

I have 3 activities: **Splash** (launcher), **Login**, **Dashboard**. When app is opened Splash waits some time and then starts Login, `finish`ing itself. Then user can then navigate from Login to Dashboard.

I want to maintain a single instance of the app whenever the user clics on the home button, or is directed towards the app by a browsable Intent. So that the user is returned to where he or she was before switching the app.

The following is the behaviour with `android:launchMode="standard"` and `singleInstancePerTask` (red squares are finished activities)
[image: standard mode]

`singleTask` behaves similar to the additional web intent for standard mode, i can add logic to Splash so that it interrupts processings and finish if it is not root:
[image: single taask]

Lastly If I choose `singleInstance`, the following happens:

[image: single instance]
This seems to work, but there is something that I don't understand.  **Why is the second Splash ignoring the Intent to launch Login activity?**. The logic tells me that a Login #2 should've launched.

Manifest in matter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.testintentflags">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestIntentFLags">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="demo.intents.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using a splashscreen activity at all. Have you looked at the [APIs specifically built for building a splash screen correctly](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen)?

Comment: Generally speaking you should not be using `singleTask` or `singleInstance` launch modes for this purpose. it is not necessary and makes more problems than it solves. Please edit your question and post your manifest.

Comment: You need to craft the web `Intent` to that it looks like the user pressing the HOME button. Please edit your question and show the web `Intent` that you are using.

Comment: @DavidWasser _"You need to craft the web Intent to that it looks like the user pressing the HOME button"_. Wouldn't that break support for [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links#android-app-links)? (which OP appears to be using).

Comment: @Michael Please see my answer. I suggested a way of doing this that doesn't require any special crafting of the web `Intent`, although if OP is using app links he could craft a browser `Intent` instead as an alternative. This doesn't "break support for app links"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things going on here, I'll try to address these:

First off, using `launchMode="singleInstance"` is problematic here, because you have not declared any `taskAffinity` for any of your activities. So your `SplashActivity` and your other activities have the same (default) `taskAffinity` which tells Android that all these activities want to run in the same task, which conflicts with your launch mode declaration of `SplashActivity`. This is bad, and you shouldn't do it. If you really want to have activities running in separate tasks, you should ensure that they have different `taskAffinity` so as not to cause confusion.

Secondly, you wrote:

> This seems to work, but there is something that I don't understand.
> **Why is the second Splash ignoring the Intent to launch Login
> activity?.** The logic tells me that a Login #2 should've launched.

What is happening here is this: When `SplashActivity` calls `startActivity()` to launch `LoginActivity`, the `Intent` used contains `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` set (because `SplashActivity` is declared with `launchMode="singleInstance"` so it has to launch other activities into a new task), so Android looks for an existing task that has `LoginActivity` as its root `Activity`. If it didn't find one, it would simply launch a new instance of `LoginActivity` into a new task. However, in this case, it finds one (this is task #2 in your diagram), so instead, it just brings that task to the foreground **without launching a new instance of `LoginActivity`**.

This is the same behaviour as what happens when you have an app running, then press the HOME button and then click the app icon for that app again. Android doesn't launch a new instance of the app's root `Activity` in this case, it simply looks for an existing task that has the app's launch `Activity` as its root `Activity` and brings that task to the foreground in whatever state it was in.

My suggestion for you is as follows:

- Get rid of the use of the special launch modes `singleInstance` and `singleTask`
- Create a new `BridgeActivity` which is used as a bridge between the web browser and your app. This `Activity` should have the `<intent-filter>` for the browser `Intent`.
- The `BridgeActivity` should check if it is the root `Activity` in its task. If it is not, it means that it has been launched into an existing task that was brought to the foreground and it can just quietly `finish()` in `onCreate()`.
- If `BridgeActivity` detects that it is the root of its task, it can launch `SplashActivity` (make sure to set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`) to begin a new task (since there obviously wasn't already an existing task of your app)
- `BridgeActivity` should be declared so that it doesn't end up in the task stack history or in the list of recent tasks (`noHistory="true"` and `excludeFromRecents="true"`)

Comment: Great, thank you, that was the explanation I was looking for. I hope that was defined in Android docs.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. The use of `taskAffinity` is badly/incorrectly documented and the way Android decides whether to launch a new `Activity` or simply bring the **matching task** forward is not clearly documented and probably not where you would necessarily find it. But that's why we have Stackoverflow! ;-)